# i have problem with my mongodb database before now its worked but i have no idea why now dont work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service;enabled;vendor preset:enabled)

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-01-06 22:47:17 UTC; 19s ago

```
 Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
```

Process: 28962 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Main PID: 28962 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

please help

ubuntu@ip-172-31-34-212:/var/log/mongodb$ sudo cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log | tail -n 10
2021-01-06T10:56:24.117+0000 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (28) [1609930584:114712][11189:0x7fbb8a654700], file:collection-4-8251526658303988689.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __posix_file_write, 541: /var/lib/mongodb/collection-4-8251526658303988689.wt: handle-write: pwrite: failed to write 4096 bytes at offset 20480: No space left on device Raw: [1609930584:114712][11189:0x7fbb8a654700], file:collection-4-8251526658303988689.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __posix_file_write, 541: /var/lib/mongodb/collection-4-8251526658303988689.wt: handle-write: pwrite: failed to write 4096 bytes at offset 20480: No space left on device
2021-01-06T10:56:24.117+0000 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (28) [1609930584:117123][11189:0x7fbb8a654700], file:collection-4-8251526658303988689.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __ckpt_process, 641: collection-4-8251526658303988689.wt: fatal checkpoint failure: No space left on device Raw: [1609930584:117123][11189:0x7fbb8a654700], file:collection-4-8251526658303988689.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __ckpt_process, 641: collection-4-8251526658303988689.wt: fatal checkpoint failure: No space left on device
2021-01-06T10:56:24.118+0000 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1609930584:118578][11189:0x7fbb8a654700], file:collection-4-8251526658303988689.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_panic, 490: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic Raw: [1609930584:118578][11189:0x7fbb8a654700], file:collection-4-8251526658303988689.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_panic, 490: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2021-01-06T10:56:24.120+0000 F  -        [WTCheckpointThread] Fatal Assertion 50853 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 414
2021-01-06T10:56:24.120+0000 F  -        [WTCheckpointThread]

***aborting after fassert() failure

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227003/discussion-on-question-by-user3202758-i-have-problem-with-my-mongodb-database-be).

Answer (score 2):

Message clearly say "No space left on device"  , extend the dbPath partition and you will start without issues ...

Comment: hi, nice but why do you think dbPath is the issue instead of the storage of the AWS instance?

Comment: since the wt files seems to be located in the dbPath default location : /var/lib/mongodb/collection-4-8251526658303988689.wt  if there is no other partition mounted in this path , apparently you are right the issue is with partition of the AWS instance which is same with the dbPath and it need to be extended ...

Comment: Yes, but also, as far as I remember, mongod assigns a default of 5% or so to storage, I can't really check that now, you could try to find it. So the limit of storage could be changed by changing the configuration file.

Comment: Mongo allocate 5% for oplog when partition is empty , but now apparently it is 100% full and best way is to be extended , wiredTiger is very sensitive on deletion , maybe only the default diagnostic data inside dbPath can be removed , they must be located in /var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data/